# Advanced Java Generics question: why do we need to specify redundant information

Tags: java, generics, dao

I've got some generic class for my JPA model POJO that goes like this:

```
public interface Identifiable<PK extends Serializable> {
    PK getUniqueId();
}

public interface GenericDao<T extends Identifiable<PK>> {
    public T findById(PK id);
}
```

This code won't compile. For this to work, I need to specify

```
public interface GenericDao<T extends Identifiable<PK>, PK extends Serializable>
```

But that's redundant information !! The fact that T extends Identifiable imply that a PK type will be specified for the Identifiable instance and that this is the type to use for the DAO's PK.

How can I make this work without redundant information ?

Thanks, Fred

---

**Edit:** Simplified example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
public interface WatchableDao<T extends Watchable<?>>
```

(i.e. it's a `Watchable<Something>` but I don't care what `Something` is)

I haven't tried it, but it's worth a go.

EDIT: Post question edit, it seems that you really do need PK as a type parameter to the interface. In that case, I believe you have to effectively repeat the constraint as you are doing. Yes, it's redundant, but I think it's simpler than the language having to specify what *effective* constraints would apply to PK based on its use as a type argument elsewhere. If it's any consolation, the same is true in C#.

It also makes the constraints on PK clear from just the interface itself, rather than having to look at another interface to see what's feasible.

Comment: It doesn't work because GenericDao<T, PK> was needing PK to be specified... I simplified my example. You should understand it better now.

Comment: It won't compile since function public T findById(PK id) need the PK generic type to be defined. Maybe I'll just live with redundant info...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Event if it's a negative answer I'll thread that as accepted :)